# QSlider show min, max and current value

Tags: c++, qt, qslider

Is it possible to show minimum, maximum and current selected value of QSlider? Of course I can use labels to display this, but I think there must be such possibility in QSlider

Comment: I think you will have to subclass it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have two options..

1) as being mentioned in comments - sub - class

2) add as many QLabel's as you like with QSlider as a **parent**, install eventHandler() on QSlider to catch resize event to proper position them, and obviously handle scroll events, so you can update them... So labels will just float on top of QSlider

Answer (score 10):

Here is my quick implementation of a fancy slider which subclass qslider to displays the current value just below the slider handle into a tooltip.

Header

```
#ifndef FANCYSLIDER_H
#define FANCYSLIDER_H

#include <QSlider>

class FancySlider : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit FancySlider(QWidget *parent = 0);
    explicit FancySlider(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    virtual void sliderChange(SliderChange change);
};

#endif // FANCYSLIDER_H
```

Cpp

```
#include "FancySlider.h"

#include <QStyleOptionSlider>
#include <QToolTip>

FancySlider::FancySlider(QWidget * parent)
    : QSlider(parent)
{
}

FancySlider::FancySlider(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget * parent)
    : QSlider(orientation, parent)
{
}

void FancySlider::sliderChange(QAbstractSlider::SliderChange change)
{
    QSlider::sliderChange(change);

    if (change == QAbstractSlider::SliderValueChange )
    {
        QStyleOptionSlider opt;
        initStyleOption(&opt);

        QRect sr = style()->subControlRect(QStyle::CC_Slider, &opt, QStyle::SC_SliderHandle, this);
        QPoint bottomRightCorner = sr.bottomLeft();

        QToolTip::showText(mapToGlobal( QPoint( bottomRightCorner.x(), bottomRightCorner.y() ) ), QString::number(value()), this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my implementation, without subclassing. Instanciate a slider with a label at right, showing the current value of slider :

```
QWidget *tmpW1 = new QWidget(this);
QHBoxLayout *tmpH1 = new QHBoxLayout(this);
QLabel *tmpLabel = new QLabel("0");

QSlider *tmpSlider = new QSlider(Qt::Horizontal, this);
tmpSlider->setMinimum(0);
tmpSlider->setMaximum(10);
tmpSlider->setValue(5);

tmpH1->addWidget(tmpSlider);
tmpH1->addWidget(tmpLabel);
tmpW1->setLayout(tmpH1);

QObject::connect(tmpSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, this, [=] () {
    tmpLabel->setText(QString::number(tmpSlider->value()));
});
```